# Is it possible to download full iCloud backup for iOS 13?

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, data-recovery

I remember it used to be possible to download the full iCloud backup. However, after trying a bunch of tools (Dr Fone, syncios, easeUS, iPhone backup extractor) online that claims to download iCloud backup, none of them actually works. Is there any way to do this currently?

Answer (score -1):

It's probably important to note that using any method that doesn't require you signing in won't work as iCloud backups are encrypted and you’d need to be logged in to access them.

I'd be hesitant even trying third-party tools as they don't use Apple's official login process, making it unclear how they manage your credentials and if they keep them safe.

Regardless, the only offical way to download an iCloud backup is by (restoring it to a device, if required, and then) backing it up to a computer using iTunes where the [backup file](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204215#findiTunes) can then be stored elsewhere.

Comment: iCloud backups can be read by apple

Answer (score -2):

Yes what you ask is generally and technically possible and also requires some skill and/or funding to perform.

If you intend to access your account, I’d read over the Apple terms and conditions carefully. The US license has language that prohibits anyone from accessing the service (which has the data) through automated means including scripts.

Then decide if you need a lawyer to make sure you are not in violation of the terms before you access your data with a tool or script like the commercially available tools like Elcomsoft phone breaker suite.

- https://www.elcomsoft.com/eppb.html

I would instead use Apple’s iOS and hardware to download your full backup unless you’re sure you need other means and have evaluated the legality and risk to access the data in a way that’s potentially not licensed.

The terms also explain what a “full backup” is and is not - so you might need to use a backup method other than iTunes based on what full means to you.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207428
- https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/icloud/en/terms.html

> The following content is not included in your iCloud backup: content purchased from the iTunes Store, App Store, or Apple Books, media synced from your computer, and your photo library if you have enabled iCloud Photo Library

Comment: this is not an answer IMO. I get the legality issue mentioned here but that imo could be a comment!?

Comment: I’m not sure ios 15 and 16 are relevant for iOS 13 era design. Maybe a new question would be better than fitting this into a comment @Daij-Djan I do appreciate the feedback